# How can I make the internal node representation smaller in the plotting function of the partykit/glmertree package in R?

Tags: r, rpart, party

I am working with the `glmertree` package in R, which is an extension of the `partykit` package. I am trying to plot a model using the `glmertree` plotting function, which simply extends the `partykit` plotting function. I would like to make the circles for the internal nodes smaller in my plot so that they do not all overlap. I have extensively researched the ip_args (inner panel args) option for a party kit plot, but all I have managed to do is change the font size or the font color or what is printed in the internal node- I cannot change the circle size. Can anyone help with this?

[Default plot, made with the code 
plot(glmr_reasonable)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epbg6.png)

Using the code:

```
ip_args=list(abbreviate=FALSE, pval=FALSE, gp=gpar(cex=0.5, col="red", pin=c(0.25, 0.25))) 

plot(glmr_reasonable, ip_args=ip_args)
```

I was able to make the following changes:

[New plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM8du.png)

However, I don't want red text and tiny font, I want smaller circles. Does anyone know how to help?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about **[How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and 
**[how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)**.
This will make it much easier for others to help you. In the question above, giving a limited data set would give something to play with for those who want to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `node_inner()` panel function currently determines how large the label for the longest splitting variable name is and chooses the size of the ellipse correspondingly. However, due to a bug (that I just fixed on R-Forge) the `gpar` settings within the `ip_args` had not been processed correctly.

If you have one (or a few) variable name(s) that is/are quite long like `STABLE_RESIDENCE` then *all* ellipses become larger. (It would just look awkward to make this only larger for some nodes.) To save space you can either abbreviate the text or decrease the font size:

1. By setting `ip_args = list(abbreviate = 10)`, say, only those variable names that are longer than 10 would get abbreviated automatically, thus making all ellipses smaller.
2. By decreasing the `fontsize` throughout the entire plot you will also make the ellipses smaller, e.g., `plot(..., gp = gpar(fontsize = 9))`.
3. Decreasing the `fontsize` just locally in the inner nodes (but not the rest of the tree) will also make the ellipses smaller, e.g., `ip_args = list(gp = gpar(fontsize = 9))`.

The last point did not work correctly up to now but I have just committed a fix to R-Forge. (To install this you currently have to check out and install by hand because R-Forge's auto-builder currently seems to hang...)